# passport-local-sequelize vulnerability issue

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am  trying to install passport-local-sequelize but when I run the command to install it I get this:

```
npm install passport-local-sequelize

up to date, audited 137 packages in 2s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 2 critical)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details
```

I would like to know if there is a problem with using the library even with that or what alternative do I have